# How can i save my matrix variable into a dictionary and keep adding a new matrix to that dictionary, in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, file, matrix, save

So I have a code in Python that has a 10x6 matrix, **CurrentPop**, and I was trying to save it in a dictionary and then to a file:

```
# Save Progress Results to the file
Results_trainPSO_Firestation =[{'Fitness':CurrentPop[:,n_par],'Population':CurrentPop[:,:n_par]}]
np.save('Results_trainPSO_Firestation.txt', Results_trainPSO_Firestation)
```

But after that I have a cycle `for` with 50 iterations, that updates all the values in the matrix **CurrentPop**, and I want to save the "new" CurrentPop at each iteration, add it to the dictionary, and to the file created before, but I don't know how or if using a dictionary is the best option for this.

I tried this inside the cycle `for`, but it doesn't work:

```
# Save Progress Results to the file
Results_trainPSO_Firestation[0]['Fitness'].append(CurrentPop[:, n_par])
Results_trainPSO_Firestation[0]['Population'].append(CurrentPop[:, :n_par])
np.save('Results_trainPSO_Firestation.txt', Results_trainPSO_Firestation)
```

It gives me this error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Answer (score 0):

### You probably don't need to do what you did

First of all, the error you are getting is because you try to call `.append` method on an `numpy.ndarray` object which does not have this method. If you want to fix that, take a look at what I wrote down.

Secondly, when you store a `numpy.ndarray` object in a dictionary, it will be stored by its reference. This means that any changes you do to `CurrentPop` will also be reflected in `Results_trainPSO_Firestation['population']` (because they both refer to the same object).
So you can do something like:

```
my_matrix = np.ndarray([[1, 2, 3]]) # initializing some matrix
data_to_write = {'matrix': my_matrix}
write_to_file(data_to_write) # any code of yours that write the content of the dictionary to a file

my_matrix[0][0] = 100 # Modify your matrix anyway you wish
write_to_file(data_to_write) # Write to file again - your changes to my_matrix will be reflected.
```

### As for the `.append` method:

Notice that on your first snippet you wrote

```
Results_trainPSO_Firestation =[{'Fitness':CurrentPop[:,n_par],'Population':CurrentPop[:,:n_par]}]
```

This line is basically saying that `Results_trainPSO_Firestation['Population']` is `CurrentPop[:,:n_par]`, which I assume is a type `numpy.ndarray`. `numpy.ndarray` is a type that does not have an `append` method (that you are trying to use on your second snippet).

Perhaps you wanted to use:

```
Results_trainPSO_Firestation[0]['Population'] = CurrentPop[:, :n_par]
```

Instead of

```
Results_trainPSO_Firestation[0]['Population'].append(CurrentPop[:, :n_par]
```

And if you're still having problem, try:

```
del Results_trainPSO_Firestation[0]['Population']
Results_trainPSO_Firestation[0]['Population'] = CurrentPop[:, :n_par]
```

**Note you have the same problem with 'Fitness'.**